# How can I store for loop in a variable?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

How can I store this in a `$_var` variable ?

```
$s_number = 5;
$spn      = '6';

echo "'Landscapes':[";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $s_number; $i++)
{
    echo "'".$spn."/"."content"."/".$i.".png"."'".", ";
}
echo "]";
```

Comment: do you want to save this php code in variable?

Comment: Store what in the `$_var`?

Comment: I think he wants to store the echoe'd text in a var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is bit vague though it seems probably you are looking for this,

```
 $string = "'Landscapes':[";
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $s_number; $i++) {
     $string .= "'".$spn."/"."content"."/".$i.".png"."'".", ";
 } 
 $string .= "]";
 echo $string;
```

Comment: @iSUSO - pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Other suggestions that use strings are fine, but I prefer to create arrays for tasks like this:

```
$s_number = 5;
$spn = '6';
$landscapes_array = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $s_number; $i++) {
    $landscapes_array[] = "'".$spn."/"."content"."/".$i.".png"."'".", ";
}
$landscapes = "'Landscapes':[" . implode('', $landscapes_array) . "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try putting the for loop in a function passing your variables and then return the values to a new variable. That's like saving a loop in a variable.